# Access child object fields on custom classic email templates

Tags: email-template, master-detail, salesforce-classic, child-to-parent

In my use case, I have 2 objects called 'Object A' and 'Object B'. 'Object B' contains a master-detail relationship to Object A. I have an email alert which has been set up on 'Object A'. In the corresponding email template is as below and it is working fine.

```
Hi {!ObjectA__c.OwnerFirstName},

Congratulations! Your request is approved by. Please proceed with completing your classes and we wish you the all the best.
```

My current requirement is that I need to merge child object field into this email. So that I have added **{!ObjectB__c.Status__c}** as folllows.

```
Hi {!ObjectA__c.OwnerFirstName},

Congratulations! Your request is approved by
{!ObjectB__c.Status__c}
. Please proceed with completing your classes and we wish you the all the best.
```

But it is not working. Appreciate if someone can help me out regarding this conern

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things here - your Email Alert is based on the parent, Object A.  So it wouldn't be able to reference Object B records like that because it wouldn't know which child record you were referring to.

However, cross object merge fields aren't currently supported - see this:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000g7bmQAA

Normal workaround is to put a formula field onto your primary object that pulls the info you need from the related objects, and then reference that in your email template.  But again - think about whether you want your primary object to be on your parent or child object - in your case I would be making the child object the primary object of the email alert.

Comment: Currently these email alerts are firing through a process builder which has been set on Object A. As per your comment, if I am setting email alert on Object B and doing changes accordingly, do I have to set the process builder on Object B? Summarizingly, the object of email alerts and the process builder should be the same?

Comment: Yes, process builder will pass the triggering record through to the email alert, so it should be triggered from Object B.